# Storing the return of a function into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a SHA1 hash function that returns an array of 20 characters, unfortunately  it does not store it anywhere is there a way to store this return in array. Below is what I have so far. I get a warning saying..

> C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'SHA1_Hash'

```
uint8_t* SHA1_Hash;
SHA1_Hash[20] = util_sha1_finalize(&AuthContext, SHA1_Hash);
```

Comment: Can you show us how `util_sha1_finalize` is defined? There is more than one way to "return an array".

Comment: FYI, for an array of 20 elements, `array[20]` is out of bounds.

Comment: `SHA1_Hash[20]` accesses the non-existent 21st element of an array. It does not size an array or whatever you think you want it to do. `SHA1_Hash = util_sha1_finalize(&AuthContext, SHA1_Hash);` will assign the has returned from the function to your pointer.

Comment: The reason for the NULL pointer error is the heavens smiled upon you and the uninitialized  variable `SHA1_Hash` happened to point at NULL, an easily testable parking space for pointers that are not pointed at a valid object. You could just as easily have found it pointing at a valid block of your program's storage and overwritten whatever happened to sit there. The buggy code would have looked like it worked and some innocent line of code at some point in the future would have crashed or spat out a wrong answer. Very tricky to find a bug like this sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This part dereference potentially NULL pointer:

> SHA1_Hash[20]

This code so suspiciously but you can save the returned value of hash function in another variable or you can initialize and check pointer value outside of function. See more details about warning here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-160